# How to make a fortune like bash-script

Tags: bash

So I'm new to bash, and I found a bunch of files used in fortune commandline app as source of its motivation message in this kinda pattern:

```
Quote 1 line 1
Quote 1 line 2
%
Quote 2 line 1
Quote 2 line 2
Quote 2 line 3
%
```

And I'm wondering how to make bash script to print randomly those quotes. Skipping random part, I'm truly curious, how can I print each line as group of quotes separated by that `%`?
Thanks

Comment: Oops, you forgot to post your code! StackOverflow is about helping people fix their code and learn how to improve their skills, it's not a free coding service. Any code is better than no code at all. Meta-code, even, will demonstrate how you're thinking a program should work even if you don't know how to write it. Show us your work so far in an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), the result you were expecting and what you got, and we'll help you figure it out. Also, bash isn't really the best solution for this kind of text processing. I'd recommend doing this in awk, as a minimum.

Comment: @ghoti ohh sorry, I m still sketching. But thanks for pointing to use `awk`. Sorry for useless questions.

Comment: Personally, I'd totally use bash, or maybe perl.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77338116/parse-fortune-database-file-with-plain-bash provides better answer than what’s suggested here.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Idiot that I am, I didn't read the requirements properly.

## A *non-portable* GNU sed one-liner (ymmv):

```
sed -n "$(grep -n % quoteFile|shuf|head -1|sed 's!:%!,/%/!')"' {/%/!p; /!%/p}' quoteFile
```

That's a subshell that uses `grep -n % quoteFile` to get the line numbers of the %'s, a `shuf` to randomize them, a `head -1` to grab the first of the shuffled delimiter line numbers, and a `sed` to change `5:%` to `5,/%/` as the range specifier for the external call to sed. Note the switch from double to single quotes so I didn't have to treat the !'s specially (my bash emulation is bitchy).

The outer `sed` jumps to the specified line number of the `shuf`'d % and prints all lines that don't have a % until it sees the next %.

This *does* mean that you would need a leading %, and should remove the trailing %.

## Using Perl:

```
perl -ne 'BEGIN{ $/=q{%}; } s/^\n|%$//g; push @F, $_ if /./; END{ print $F[int(rand(@F))]; }' quoteFile
```

> perl -ne

-n means read each line and execute the code against it, kinda like awk.
-e defines the input expression string (the code)

> BEGIN{ $/=q{%}; }

Before reading anything, set the input record separator to a percent sign.

> s/^\n|%$//g;

For each "line", strip leading newlines from any previous delimiter, aand training percent signs.

> push @F, $_ if /./;

Push the record read onto the F array if it had any characters in it (the last one won't, after the strip of the leading newline.)

> END{ print $F[int(rand(@F))]; }

after all the records have been processed print one at random.

All input will be read from any provided `quoteFile`

Have fun.

Comment: If I get time, I'll figure out syntax for that one-liner not to require changing the leading/trailing %'s.

Comment: Thiss one is the fastesttt... thanks

Comment: Your "bash one-liner" contains nothing that is specifically bash, and contains non-portable sed code. If you adjust the sed code so that it actually works, I'd recommend re-branding this one as a "POSIX (and bash) shell one-liner".

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you've got quotes in a file called 'fortunes.txt' try this pure Bash solution:

```
#! /bin/bash

declare -a fortunes=()  # Array of fortunes
declare -i curr_idx=0   # Index of fortune currently being read

while IFS= read -r line ; do
    [[ $line == '%' ]] && curr_idx+=1 || fortunes[curr_idx]+="$line"$'\n'
done < fortunes.txt

printf '%s\n' "${fortunes[RANDOM % ${#fortunes[*]}]}"
```

That code takes about 1 second to run on a one megabyte 'fortunes.txt' file on my oldish Linux system.  It's not practical for significantly larger input files.

Comment: Whoa I like this, this is more simple than what I've come up with. But the drawback is it needs to read all the line first. I'll post my messy code...

Answer (score 0):

I just read @pjh and @paul hodges answer due to internet connection problem, I like their simplicity. Tho I'm already come up on my own with this messy one:
(this doesn't need to read entire lines of file first, just specific line)

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

randqu_file=fortunes.txt

rando_line=$(( (RANDOM % $(wc -l < $randqu_file) + 1 )))

while [[ $(sed -n "${rando_line}p" $randqu_file) != '%' || $rando_line -eq $(wc -l < $randqu_file) ]]; do
    rando_line=$((rando_line - 1))
    [[ $rando_line -eq 0 ]] && break
done

rando_line=$((rando_line + 1))

while [[ $(sed -n "${rando_line}p" $randqu_file) != '%' ]]; do
    sed -n "${rando_line}p" $randqu_file
    rando_line=$((rando_line + 1))
    [[ $rando_line -gt $(wc -l < $randqu_file) ]] && break
done
```