# Parse fortune database file with plain bash

Tags: bash, parsing, fortune-mod

When I parse [fortune database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortune_(Unix)) file with

```bash
$ mapfile -d '%' -t QUOTES < ~/.sigfile
$ echo ${#QUOTES}
302
$
```

However when I parse the same database with Python I get (correctly) much less length of the list:

```py
>>> import re
>>> fort_arr = re.split(r"\n%\n", open("/home/matej/.sigfile").read())
>>> print(len(fort_arr))
202
>>>
```

Any idea what do I wrong? (and no, I couldn’t install `/usr/bin/fortune`, all parsing must be done with plain bash and basic Unix utilities).

Yes, there is [almost a duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52948263/how-to-make-a-fortune-like-bash-script), but it is closed and it does provide very awkward and complicated suggestions.

Comment: Add output of `file ~/.sigfile` to your question (no comment here).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a fortune like bash-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52948263/how-to-make-a-fortune-like-bash-script)

Comment: There are probably % characters in the quotes themselves that are being treated as delimiters by `mapfile`.

Comment: `echo ${#QUOTES}` is the same as `echo ${#QUOTES[0]}`, it prints the length of the first entry of the array. Try `echo ${#QUOTES[@]}` for the number of entries.

Comment: I said a standard fortune database. It’s here https://mcepl.fedorapeople.org/tmp/_sigfile and no aside from `%` characters as delimiters there is no other one.

Comment: I confirm that with the file you indicate `echo ${#QUOTES[@]}` prints 202.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet Please, make this into an independent answer so I can approve it, please.

Comment: Done, see below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`echo ${#QUOTES}` is the same as `echo ${#QUOTES[0]}`, it prints the length of the first entry of the array. Try `echo "${#QUOTES[@]}"` for the number of entries.